# What's the difference between gig[x_] := Sequence[x^2]; Map[gig, list1, {3}] and Map[Apply[## &, #^2] &, list1, {3}]

Tags: list-manipulation

Here they are.

1st:

```
list1={1, {2, {3, {4}, 5}, 6}, 7}; 
Map[Apply[## &, #^2] &, list1, {3}]
```

Ouput:

### `{1, {2, {9, 16, 25}, 6}, 7}`

2nd :

```
gig[x_] := Sequence[x^2];
list1={1, {2, {3, {4}, 5}, 6}, 7};
Map[gig, list1, {3}]
```

Output:

### `{1, {2, {9, {16}, 25}, 6}, 7}`

**What's the difference between these two? Can anyone explain the output?**

**How can I correct the second one into the first one with function `gig`?**

Comment: `Apply[##&` is more `Sequence @@` rather than `Sequence @ `.

Comment: @Kuba how to get it done in 2nd ?

Comment: by doing `Sequence @@ (x^2)`